# in scala, comparing Int 7 with char '7' gives false

Tags: scala, dictionary, integer, key, character

Why do the following expressions evaluate to `false`?

```
scala> 7 == '7'
res0: Boolean = false

scala> 7.toChar == '7'
res1: Boolean = false                                                                                                                                                         

scala> 7.toChar equals '7'
res2: Boolean = false
```

What is the correct way to compare number with characters?

My problem is that I have the following `Map[Char, Int]()`,

```
Map(7 -> 2, 1 -> 1, 5 -> 1, 0 -> 1)
```

and

```
map getOrElse(7.toChar, 0)
```

returns `0`. I would expect the result to be `2`, since my map contains `2 -> 7`.

Comment: Why would you expect `'7'` to be equal to `7`? Character `'7'` has integer value 55, not 7. Also, don't be fooled by the REPL. It doesn't display single and double quotes in the output. You may be seeing `Map(7 -> 2, 1 -> 1, 5 -> 1, 0 -> 1)` in the output, but it's really `Map('7' -> 2, '1' -> 1, '5' -> 1, '0' -> 1)`. It is a `Map[Char, Int]`, not a `Map[Int, Int]`

Comment: Thanx Jubobs, I can see why you replied me with that answer, may be i have chosen wrong title, but real problem is, It is a Map[Char, Int] as u correctly identified, now the task I could not achieve is that I have map Map(7 -> 2, 1 -> 1, 5 -> 1, 0 -> 1) and i m trying to do : for(z <- 0 to 9 ) println( (map getOrElse(z.toChar,0)))    , Now what should i do to get output printed as 2 when z is 7. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do the following expressions evaluate to `false`?
>
> ```
> scala> 7 == '7'
> res0: Boolean = false
> ```

[The numeric value of the character `'7'` is `55`](http://fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0037/), `55` is not equal to `7`, ergo, the expression evaluates to `false`.

> ```
> scala> 7.toChar == '7'
> res1: Boolean = false                                                                                                                                                         
>
> scala> 7.toChar equals '7'
> res2: Boolean = false
> ```

[The character value of the number `7` is the `BEL` character](http://fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0007/), not the character `'7'`, ergo, these two expressions evaluate to `false`.

> What is the correct way to compare number with characters?
>
> My problem is that I have the following `Map[Char, Int]()`,
>
> ```
> Map(7 -> 2, 1 -> 1, 5 -> 1, 0 -> 1)
> ```

The Scala character literal for the character `7` is `'7'`, so you can just use that:

```
map getOrElse('7', 0)
// => 2
```

If, for some reason, you only have the number `7` available, the *easiest* way would be to change your `Map` to a map of numbers to numbers:

```
val map = Map(7 -> 2, 1 -> 1, 5 -> 1, 0 -> 1)

map getOrElse(7, 0)
// => 2
```

If you can't do that, then what you *really* want is the character resulting from the string representation of the number in question, not the character value of the number:

```
map getOrElse(7.toString.charAt(0), 0)
// => 2
```

Comment: Thankyou Jorg, map getOrElse(7.toString.charAt(0), 0)  was solution i was looking for :)